# AngularJS with AngularFire 0.5.0 - $remove item doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I just wanted to work more on my first little Angular project and I updated AngularFire from 0.3.0 to 0.5.0 and nothing really works anymore. I was able to get the database access back and also to add items to my list. But the remove function doesn't work anymore. Before I udpated AngularFire, I used splice(index,1) to remove an item. I also tried to use the new $remove from 0.5.0 but it just removes all items from the list, even I add a key.

Thats my list repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, earning) in earnings | orderByPriority">
    <td>{{earning.date}}</td>
    <td>{{earning.description}}</td>
    <td>{{earning.price}} €</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeEarning(key)">
        Löschen
      </button>
    </td>
```

As you can see, it just creates a tr with data and each item has a delete button. When I click the delete button on a specific item, only this should be removed and not all from the list.

My JS code now:

```
function BalanceCtrl($scope, $log, $http, $firebase) {
    var dbEarnings = new Firebase('https://*******.firebaseio.com/Earnings');
    $scope.earnings = $firebase(dbEarnings);

    $scope.addEarning = function() {
        $scope.earnings.$add({date:$scope.FormEarningDate,  description:$scope.FormEarningDescription, price:$scope.FormEarningPrice});    
        $scope.FormEarningDate = '';
        $scope.FormEarningDescription = '';
        $scope.FormEarningPrice = '';
        $scope.updateEarning();}

        $scope.removeEarning = function (key) {
            $scope.earnings.$remove(key);   
        }
```

It doesn't work somehow to remove only the specific item from the list. It all worked fine with 0.3.0. Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: That seems to correct code and $remove works as expected in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dFQmxUtIbKlhjiW1WV1X?p=preview - can you double check that the value of 'key' is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `orderByPriority` filter converts the collection to an array, causing `key` to become a numeric index (0, 1, 2, …)—it's no longer the Firebase name.

From http://angularfire.com/documentation.html:

> The orderByPriority filter is provided by AngularFire to convert an
>   object returned by $firebase into an array. The objects in the array
>   are ordered by priority (as defined in Firebase). Additionally, **each
>   object in the array will have a $id property** defined on it, which will
>   correspond to the key name for that object.

So use `removeEarning(earning.$id)`.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/pJf2drPwhFAVCuaBSPHq?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks that helped :) It's working. Now I can go on with my app.

Comment: @trevor: When you do this on child data the $id isn't generated. See http://plnkr.co/edit/pElPkk Is this intended? Creating a child reference does work.

Comment: @RichardVan'tHoenderdaal Yep, that's been my experience too. I use `ng-init` to store a `.$child(…)` reference.